# How do I correctly notify the Blazor UI that my user state has changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am currently learning asp.net core and blazor, and have come across an issue with little documentation. I have a Server side Blazor app and am re doing authentication to use local storage and the ServerAuthenticationStateProvider. This code is based off [this guide](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/), here is my current implementation of the state provider:

**MyAuthenticationStateProvider.cs**

```
namespace BlazorApp
{
    public class MyAuthenticationStateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

        public MyAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorage)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _localStorage = localStorage;
        }
        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
            {
                return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
            }

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt"));

            return new AuthenticationState(user);
        }

        public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string token)
        {
            var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt"));
            var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);

        }
```

**LoginControl.cs**

```
@page "/loginControl"
@inject IAuthService AuthService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

    <AuthorizeView>

        <Authorized>

            <b>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</b>

            <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
               href="logout?returnUrl=/"
               target="_top">Logout</a>

        </Authorized>

        <Authorizing>
            <b>Authentication in progress</b>
        </Authorizing>

        <NotAuthorized>

            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Email"
                   @bind="@email" />

            &nbsp;&nbsp;

            <input type="password"
                   placeholder="Password"
                   @bind="@password" />

            <button class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
                    @onclick="@createSession">
                Login
            </button>

        </NotAuthorized>

    </AuthorizeView>

@code {

    string email = "";

    string password = "";

    async void createSession()
    {

        var loginRequest = new LoginRequest
        {

            Email = email,
            Password = password

        };

        await AuthService.Login(loginRequest);
    }

}
```

I would expect that after the `NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(AuthState)` is called, my login UI would refresh and the `<Authorized>` content to display. However my UI still shows the `<NotAuthorized>` content. Did I miss something to do with dispatching to the main thread?? I am Very new to all this but my Mentor mentioned something to do with this possibly having to do with being a background thread not telling the UI to re-render.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Really simple. All you need to do is:

```
StateHasChanged();
```

I just built a login control yesterday, so here are some bonus things you might want to know:

My login control has this:

```
<Login OnLogin="LoginComplete"></Login>

/// <summary>
/// This method returns the LoginResponse object 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="loginResponse"></param>
private void LoginComplete(LoginResponse loginResponse)
{
    // if the login was successful
    if (loginResponse.Success)
    {
        // Set the player
        player = loginResponse.Player;

        // refresh the UI
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

And in your control to invoke the LoginResponse delegate

```
// Get the loginResponse
LoginResponse loginResponse = await PlayerService.Login(emailAddress, password);

// if the loginResponse exists
if (NullHelper.Exists(loginResponse))
{
   // set the player
   player = loginResponse.Player;

   // Perform the Login
  await OnLogin.InvokeAsync(loginResponse);
}
```

Comment: What does your loginresponse contain? I'm not quite sure what the line `await OnLogin.InvokeAsync(loginresponse)` does

Comment: Here is the code for the LoginResponse, although this project isn't ready to be cloned yet.

https://github.com/DataJuggler/CardCounter/blob/master/Data/ObjectLibrary/Models/LoginResponse.cs

This is just a class I wrote Specific to BlackJack, so after I log the player in from the Login Control I can send a response back with a Player and his chip balance, market balance,etc. or a failed response with a message.

The Login Control in the Components Folder and the Index page is where all the code that works is.

Comment: To answer your question, here is the code for the Login Control:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/CardCounter/blob/master/Components/Login.razor

At Line 69 (at the time of this writing) the HandleLogin method calls the Player Service to perform the login, and to send the response back to the Index Page, you set the OnLoginComplete parameter at line 279:

    
[Parameter] public EventCallback<LoginResponse> OnLogin { get; set; }

Then the Index page receives the response.

Comment: After moving to Client side blazor, I came across a similar issue and remembered this answer which helped. Seems I can also user Task functions and the UI will wait for the task then update accordingly

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by redirecting the user with the navigation manager and forcing the redirecting (by doing this the app is forced to change the authState).
I only did that because `StateChanged()` wans't working.

```
NaviMngr.NavigateTo("/", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create in your CustomeStateProvider this:

```
public void NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged()
    {
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }
```

And in the Razor page, you need to first call the NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged() method from YourCustomStateProvider and then StateHasChanged after successful authorization.
I guess this works because you check the authentication state and immediately change the UI if the state has changed.

Example:

```
 _authenticationStateProvider.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I went about this wrong, server side blazor already implements `AuthenticationStateProvider`, so all I need to do is to implement something that sets the `user.identity.isauthenticated`, I am using cookies and a jet token to do this.

Comment: These are the sorts of answer providing a clue but are to vague to get anything going. Quote `all I need to do is to implement something that sets the user.identity.isauthenticated` How exactly to you do this?

Comment: You should implement AuthenticationStateProvider

Comment: I got around, implementing my own authentication library. It worked well :)